# MySQL Error Code 1064 from workbench when create a table

Tags: mysql, datatable, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table using MySQL workbench, but the error msg shows this error. Check online, it shows " often due to using reserved words, missing data in the database, or mistyped/obsolete commands. " But, I did not use any reserved words or missing data. So not sure why this error happens. Thanks!

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `assign`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8' at line 8
```

Comment: VISIBLE may not be available in your version of mysql. ALSO  `created_at` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()', does not look right do you really want to store the string CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: The error message is unconsistent to any MySQL version. So the query really sent to MySQL differs to one shown. Error message looks like the query was modified by workbench and `VISIBLE` keyword was removed incorrectly. Or maybe there exists some incorrect non-printable char between `VISIBLE` keyword and closing parenthesis after it. PS. Index is visible by default, so you do not need to specify this option explicitly.

Comment: It looks like a valid MySQL error message, and it points to exactly after `VISIBLE`.  However, when I tried it on a 5.6, I got `...near 'VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB...`.  I think this is slightly better at pointing to `VISIBLE`.